# Can we able to Move folder to another library or site using Retention Policy

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have a requirement to move set of folders from one Document Library to different library, Whether this can be achieved using SharePoint Retention Policy,like establishing a `Send to Connection` and setting Information and Expiration Policy.

I tried with documents, it is working fine, just wanted to know whether with Folder is possible or not, If Possible Please give me some steps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can set Retention Policy at Library/Folder level.
Following are the steps :

1. Goto Library --> Library settings
2. Goto Information management policy settings
   [image]
3. Goto Content Types (Change Source)
   [image]
4. Change Source Retention as Library and Folders
   [image]
5. Set retention policy
6. Done

Please refer the [Reference](https://mikesnotebook.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/sharepoint-retention-policies/) link.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i followed the same steps earlier itself but it is not working for folder

Answer (score 0):

Similar to document, you need to set up retention policy on folder content type.

Comment: Can you give me any reference link for moving folder